# Adding playa entry into field (e.g. related gallery)

Tags: playa, wygwam, richtext

Anyone know the best way to add a playa related entry (in this case a gallery) directly into a post area (wygwam or richtext field for example)? I need to have flexibility here, so could be 1 or 20 galleries per entry.

In WP you'd be able to drop in the [gallery] tag or similar (can't remember exactly, it's been a while). I was thinking there'd be some kind of integration with playa+wygwam but I can't see anything in the wygwam field config/advanced settings...

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm guessing it'd need 3rd party extension/plugin to get a list of playa-related entries and give that as a dropdown list in the field editing options then insert soemthing like: {gallery_title}

Answer (score 0):

I have not tired it, but take a look at the Shortcode plugin here: https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/shortcode

It says it work like the WordPress shortcode API which does allow you to use shortcodes to create functionality inside of text-editors.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like it might work, but not very well supported for a paid extension... hmn.